# Calculate number of sequential identical elements in a vector in R

Tags: r

If I have the vector `c(1,1,2,5,3,5,6,6,6,6,3,2,7,3,4,4,4,2,2,1)` how can I calculate the number of sequential identical elements?  The result I'm looking for would be `c(2,1,1,1,1,4,1,1,1,1,3,2,1)`. I'd prefer to avoid `for` loops please since my application of this concept is for a very long vector!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
rle(x)$lengths
```

I imagine that it is pretty efficient because it's a base function.

Comment: Astroturfing on my own behalf: if you find a need to identify sequence lengths, `cgwtools:seqle` does the same thing on a defined linear progression.